# Cannot access a method

Tags: c#, methods

I'm having error with the below code. I cannot call the function ShowUp(). Is the class Dx in wrong place or was the method declared wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Program1
{
    class Program    
    {
        public class Dx
        {
             void ShowUp()
            {
                Console.Write("Show");
                Console.Read();
                return;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dx.ShowUp();
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: ShowUp() is an _instance method_ or, in other words, a non-static method. You need to create an instance before you can call it. And there is no inheritance anywhere here.

Comment: Or you need to make ShowUp() a static method....like `public static void ShowUp()`

Comment: [C# Basics Tutorial- Methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is not static.

So either change your function definition or create an instance. And also your function needs to be internal or public as @uguraldanmaz mentioned:

1. Changing your function into static function

   *public static* void ShowUp()
2. Creating an instance of the class

   var dx = new Dx();
   dx.ShowUp();

Comment: Correct but you should emphasise the either/or aspect a little more. Maybe number the answers.

Comment: The answer makes clear sense in my opinion, if the OP wants to know the difference between an `Instance Method vs Static Method` I think the OP should google it and do some reading it's not up to @Ako to explain fully to the OP the difference